# opening client default mail application with lot of bcc address

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, mailto, bcc

I've implemented a functionality in my MVC 4 web application where the user can select a set of email addresses from a list and by clicking a button it opens the default mail client in the client computer with the selected email addresses in the `bcc` field and their own email address in the `to` field. This as a functionality works fine.

But when I started to test this with a long list of bcc email addresses, it didn't open the default email client and it didn't give any errors.

Then I tried to copy the complete url with the long list of `bcc` email addresses, paste it in a new browser window and tried to navigate from there to see if it works. then it gave me the URL too long `http exception`. I counted the number of characters in the `mailto` url which worked and it was around 1737 in Chrome. Is there anyway to override this problem and allow the user to open the default mail client in their computer with lots of `bcc` email address?

I can't use a server side solution to let them send emails as I can't allow them to use our mail server to send emails to lot of people at once.

any help is really appreciated!

thanks!